# TPL Dataflow - Why isn't my code using parallel processing?

Tags: vb.net, tpl-dataflow

Ok - first, the code...

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow

Public Class PaymentPipeLine


#Region "Properties"

    Public Property BufferBlock As BufferBlock(Of CPayment)
    Public Property TransformBlock As TransformBlock(Of CPayment, Task)
    Public Property ActionBlock As ActionBlock(Of Task)

    Public Property IncrementPayment As Action

#End Region

#Region "Constructor"
    Public Sub New(action As Action)
        Me.IncrementPayment = action
        BufferBlock = New BufferBlock(Of CPayment)
        TransformBlock = New TransformBlock(Of CPayment, Task)(Function(x As CPayment)
                                                                   Dim t = Task.Run(Sub()
                                                                                        x.process(Nothing)
                                                                                        Me.IncrementPayment.Invoke()
                                                                                    End Sub)
                                                                   Return t
                                                               End Function)
        ActionBlock = New ActionBlock(Of Task)(Sub(x As Task)
                                                   x.Wait()
                                               End Sub)
        Dim dataflowLinkOptions = New DataflowLinkOptions()
        dataflowLinkOptions.PropagateCompletion = True
        BufferBlock.LinkTo(TransformBlock, dataflowLinkOptions)
        TransformBlock.LinkTo(ActionBlock, dataflowLinkOptions)


    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "Methods"
    Public Sub Process()
        ActionBlock.Completion.Wait()
    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

Now, the code that calls this basically posts values into the BufferBlock, marks it complete when it has ran out of values, and then calls the Process() method on the pipeline...

I was expecting this to result in payments being processed in parallel, but I am seeing no improvement in performance at all (the major part of the code is an IO call to a web service to handle a payment). I can only conclude that payments are going through the pipeline one by one...

How do I get it to either:
a) Send the payments through as they are added (ie not wait for other payments to go through first), or
b) Same as a, but throttled to say perhaps only 5 go through at once?

Any ideas? Very grateful for anything you can suggest...

Martin

Comment: Thanks for the edit Peter - quite happy to discuss C# solutions - that's where my heart lies... I suspect I am using the framework incorrectly, not the language,,,#

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

I had to use an `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions` object with the `ActionBlock`'s constructor, and on that `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions` I had to set the `MaximumDegreeOfParallelization`.